# Conditional Routing - Async

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, react-router

I wanted to make a `GET` request to my server to verify if the user is authenticated or not, basically a `true or false` function. 
but it ended up being more complicated than that.

as i need an `async`,`await` function in order to get the `response` from the `request` i made. 
SO, thats what i did. but after calling the function inside a regular `sync` function which is `PrivateRoute` it only logs that the `promise` is still `pending`.

SO, i tried turning `PrivateRoute` into an `async` function. but react refused to render a `[object promise]`.

ANY IDEA what to do?

```
const isAuthenticated = async () => {
    try{
    let isAuth = await axios.get('/auth')

    console.log(isAuth.data)
    if(Object.keys(isAuth.data).length > 0) return true
    else return false

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}



const PrivateRoute = (route) => {
  const authenticated = isAuthenticated() // returns a pending promise
  console.log(authenticated)

    return (
      <Route path={route.path} render={() => {
        if (authenticated) return <Profile_Tabs />
          return <Redirect to='/' />
      }} />
    )
}

    <PrivateRoute 
      path='/profile' 
      exact={true}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `PrivateRoute` component stateful.

```
state = {
    isAuthenticated: null,
}
```

You could then do this in `componentDidMount`

```
isAuthenticated().then(isAuthenticated => this.setState({ isAuthenticated }))
```

Your render function can then be updated to check the state and conditionally render.

Comment: Ive done it like that before, its not good practice as the component has to fully load to take the redirect action. Which means the annoynmus user still can look at the protected route for like 0.5second.

Comment: You actually have 3 states for the ```isAuthenticated```. When in state ```null``` you could render a loading screen.